# Parameters for SOAP client connection

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I use asmx web service for android client application. I need soap_action, method_name, namespace and url for sample SOAP 1.1 request that written below. How can i bring out these parameters for any webservice request? The point i want to learn where these parameters come from. (ex: method_name="GetKullaniciBilgileri" it comes from after body tag)

```
POST /WebSite1/WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://kodmerkezi.net/HelloThere"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <HelloThere xmlns="http://kodmerkezi.net">
      <name>string</name>
    </HelloThere>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and i run these service as

```
http://localhost:56053/WebSite1/WebService.asmx?op=HelloThere
```

Comment: @Peter what do you mean? My english is not perfect.

Comment: RESTful services are like SOAP(web-services too), but they are reduces to simpler functions like POST,GET,REQUEST so that they can be easily implemented in services that require http

http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: @Peter thank you for your advice, but i have to use soap web-service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Namespace** = `"http://kodmerkezi.net"`

**SOAP_Method** = `"HelloThere"`

**SOAP_Action** = `"http://kodmerkezi.net/HelloThere"`

**URL** = `"http://localhost:56053/WebSite1/WebService.asmx"`

It is actually easy to extract these fields if you have the WSDL.

SOAPAction is already mentioned in the WSDL and hence you can use it from there.

SOAPAction = Namespace + MethodName

Hence, form the SOAPAction, use the first part (the part with the http://...) as the namespace and the second part as the SOAPMethod.

Also, MethodName comes after the `Body` tag which is then followed by the namespace.

```
eg. <soap:Body>
<MethodName xmlns="namespace">
```

You can get these two from here and then use SOAP_Action = Namespace + MethodName to get the SOAPAction.

Lastly, the URL refers to the URL of the ****.asmx*** file from where you are running the service.

Comment: i improved question, what should i use as url?

Comment: thanks for answer, and i need to learn how these parameters bring out.(ex: method_name="GetKullaniciBilgileri" it comes from after body tag). I ask so, because in some samples it used different, ex: "http://localhost:56053/WebSite1/WebService.asmx?wsdl" instead of "http://localhost:56053/WebSite1/WebService.asmx"

Comment: Your web services are run on your local machine. I can't view them. If you need further clarification, you need to paste the WSDL in the question. :)